# How to use systemd-nspawn with pptp?

Tags: linux, vpn, chroot, pptp, systemd-nspawn

I would like to set a container use the vpn for only network interface.

I have used the `pptpsetup` and `pon` make a pptp connection works, and got a `ppp0` interface.

Now, I want all internet connection in the systemd-nspawn container go through the `ppp0` .

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
systemd-nspawn --network-interface=ppp0
```

ppp0 will disappear from the host namespace.  You can't share one IP address with a container and not your other IP addresses.  (Apart from doing NAT).

It looks like this might require a very recent kernel though.  http://www.spinics.net/lists/netdev/msg339236.html

OR (machine is created after ppp0):

```
systemd-nspawn --private-network

ip link set dev ppp0 netns $PID
```

where $PID is the pid in the host namespace of a process in container, obtained using

```
P=$(machinectl $MACHINE_NAME show --property=Leader)
PID=${P#Leader=}
```

and `$MACHINE_NAME` is the value passed to the `-M` option of `systemd-nspawn`